# Discord.js custom image on user join

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot in JavaScript, but i need to know how to make a custom image when a user joins the server. Like this: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9Qpa.png)
I want to replace the white circle with the user's avatar and the "User Names" with the nickname of the user that joined the server. How can i make it?

Answer (score 1):

My preference is [JIMP](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp)

And how I would make your welcome message,
I would make your image with circle transparent. And remove the `USERNAME` text.

the grab the user's image with `Jimp.read()` and then copy the image it gives you into a blank image the SIZE of your welcome image.

After the user's image is copied. place the welcome image on top. then with `Jimp.print()` you can write the user's username on top.

Comment: The circle is already transparent, i added the text just to give an idea of what i want to do, thanks for your help, i'll try to do it